# what is document.getElementById?

Tags: javascript

**consider the following code:**

```
<script>
function testFunc(){
    alert('test')
}
$(function(){
    var g = document.getElementById , w = window.testFunc ;
    //g
    alert(typeof(g));
    alert(String(g));
    alert(g instanceof Object);
    alert(g instanceof Function);
    //w
    alert(typeof(w));
    alert(String(w));
    alert(w instanceof Object);
    alert(w instanceof Function);
    //run it
    alert(g('t'));
            w();

});
</script>
```

### **the code behaves the same in modern browser(chrome,IE 9,Firefox).And the result is:**

typeof => "function"
String => "function #funcName#{[native code]}"
instanceof Object => true
instanceof Function => true
it is a little weird, we can easily invoke `w` by using `()`, but for `g`, we must invoke it like this:

```
g.call(document,elementId);
```

When it comes to IE 6, the result is totally diffrent:

---

//g
**typeof => "object"**
String => "function getElementById{[native code]}"
instanceof Object => false
instanceof Function => false
//w
**typeof => "function"**
String => "function testFunc{alert('test')}"
instanceof Object => true
instanceof Function => true
what is more,we must run g and w directly by using '()', and we can not invoke g like this:

```
g.call(document,'t')
```

this will cause an error.
So here is my question: what is `document.getElementById`, function or object, and what is the diffrence between `g` and `w`?

Comment: The answer here is to stop supporting IE6 and let it die =D

Comment: The DOM interface does not have to behave  like  or even be native JavaScript functions/objects.

Comment: @Tejs: All in favor say aye: Aye!

Comment: The IE6 behaviour has been reported on IE7 as well, with `getElementsByTagName`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`document.getElementById` is a host object and it is a function.  It is not defined in EcmaScript but is part of the DOM interface.

> [4.3.8](http://es5.github.com/#x4.3.8) host object
>
> object supplied by the host environment to complete the execution environment of ECMAScript

Since it supports the `[[Call]]` operator it is also a function.

Host objects do not always obey the same rules as native objects w.r.t. `typeof` though section [11.4.3](http://es5.github.com/#x11.4.3) of EcmaScript 5 has tightened the rules somewhat.

`testFunc` is a native object, specifically a native function.

> 4.3.6 native object
>
> object in an ECMAScript implementation whose semantics are fully defined by this specification rather than by the host environment.
>
> NOTE Standard native objects are defined in this specification. Some native objects are built-in; others may be constructed during the course of execution of an ECMAScript program.

Answer (score 2):

This is a difference in user-agent implementation, one of the several hundreds one can find between IE6 and any other browser made after 1992. As long as the end functionality resembles the specifications, it makes very little difference **how** a user-agent accomplishes the functionality (except, of course, in performance)

Check out this chart of differences in implementation: http://webcoder.info/reference/BrowserFiltering.script.html

That said: don't support IE6. There's really no (and I mean **NO**) reason to worry about it any more than you'd worry about the AOL5.0 native browser.

Answer (score 1):

If your underlying problem is cross-browser compatibility, why don't you just do

```
 var g = function(id) { return document.getElementById(g) };
```

to get a guranteed ordinary first-class function that works like `getElementById`?

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById` is a function.  IE6 is just out to lunch.  Perhaps if you describe what problem you're really trying to solve, folks could help with that.

Answer (score 0):

`g` is a native function in all browsers and `w` is not. IE shows a different string result because browsers *will* format functions as strings differently, and that's why you should never convert a function to a string in the first place.

I suppose IE6 shows the `typeof` a native function as `object` but it's not an instance of anything, since it is recognized and executed by the browser as a native function.

Doesn't really matter in the end though - you never need to know the type of `document.getElementById`, and especially not in such an old browser...